# ENOTFOUND Package ng-cordova not found

Tags: cordova, bower

Help! I'm new to Cordova, node, grunt, bower, etc.

I am trying to import an existing Cordova app into Visual Studio 2015. When trying to update dependencies (by right clicking on the dependencies node in project explorer, and selecting "restore packages") I get this message in the output:

> ENOTFOUND Package ng-cordova not found

I went to a command prompt and ran:

```
npm install -g ng-cordova
```

The result was:

```
npm WARN deprecated conventional-changelog@0.0.11: Please update conventional-changelog to >1.0.0. If you are running the cli, use conventional-changelog-cli
ng-cordova@0.1.27-alpha C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ng-cordova
├── fs@0.0.2
├── q@1.4.1
├── conventional-changelog@0.0.11 (event-stream@3.1.7, lodash.assign@2.4.1)
└── gulp-git@1.12.0 (any-shell-escape@0.1.1, require-dir@0.1.0, through2@0.6.5, gulp-util@3.0.7)
```

Did that work?

I then ran:

```
bower install
```

Still got the message:

> ENOTFOUND Package ng-cordova not found

Here is the full output:

```
bower                     invalid-meta bower                     invalid-meta The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes
bower font-awesome#~4.3.0   not-cached https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#~4.3.0
bower font-awesome#~4.3.0      resolve https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#~4.3.0
bower parse-js-sdk#~1.4.0       cached https://github.com/albemuth/parse-js-sdk.git#1.4.2
bower parse-js-sdk#~1.4.0     validate 1.4.2 against https://github.com/albemuth/parse-js-sdk.git#~1.4.0
bower angular#~1.2              cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.32
bower angular#~1.2            validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2
bower bootstrap#~3.2.0          cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.2.0
bower bootstrap#~3.2.0        validate 3.2.0 against https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.2.0
bower angular-cookies#~1.2      cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.32
bower angular-cookies#~1.2    validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.2
bower angular-resource#~1.2     cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.32
bower angular-resource#~1.2   validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.2
bower angular-mocks#~1.2        cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.32
bower angular-mocks#~1.2      validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2
bower angular-animate#~1.2      cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.2.32
bower angular-animate#~1.2    validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#~1.2
bower angular-bootstrap#~0.10.0 cached https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.10.0
bower angular-bootstrap#~0.10.0         validate 0.10.0 against https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#~0.10.0
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2               cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.2.32
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2             validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#~1.2
bower angular-touch#~1.2                  cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.2.32
bower angular-touch#~1.2                validate 1.2.32 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#~1.2
bower angular-ui-router#~0.2.10           cached https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower.git#0.2.18
bower angular-ui-router#~0.2.10         validate 0.2.18 against https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower.git#~0.2.10
bower moment#~2.10.2                      cached https://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.10.6
bower moment#~2.10.2                    validate 2.10.6 against https://github.com/moment/moment.git#~2.10.2
bower angular-ui-utils#~0.1.1             cached https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#0.1.1
bower angular-ui-utils#~0.1.1           validate 0.1.1 against https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils.git#~0.1.1
bower font-awesome#~4.3.0               download https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v4.3.0.tar.gz
bower font-awesome#~4.3.0                extract archive.tar.gz
bower ng-cordova#~0.0.3                **ENOTFOUND Package ng-cordova not found**
```

I then tried installing `ngcordova` (no hyphen):

```
bower install ngcordova
```

The output still has:

> bower ng-cordova#~0.0.3 ENOTFOUND Package ng-cordova not found

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I installed ng-cordova again with --save so it updated package.json. bower still can't find it and I don't understand why:

bower ng-cordova#^0.1.27-alpha         ENOTFOUND Package ng-cordova not found

Answer (score 1):

The first command only echoed a warning about another package (the deprecated conventional-changelog @0.0.11), but `ng-cordova` was installed successfully via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-cordova). In your second command you misspelled the bower packages's name, as it is `ngCordova` as shown [on their github page](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova) on the readmes' very top. It is highly recommended to read readmes. (Might be the reason why it's called read me)

If a package can't be found by npm, you would get an error message like

```
$ npm i lkjsadflkjjlksdf

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "lkjsadflkjjlksdf"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/lkjsadflkjjlksdf
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'lkjsadflkjjlksdf' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: I edited bower.json and changed the package name to "ngCordova" bower runs now. Thanks for the help!